# What is best way to serialize a Django DateTime object into json and then instantiate a JS Date object and back?

Tags: javascript, python, datetime

First thought is strftime to convert to a sring, then split and convert each digit into int, and serialize that array/list, but that's terribly slow.

Next would be to just access each important attribute, and send an tuple/list

```
In [13]: t=now();t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.minute, t.second, t.microsecond                                                                                                                                                             
Out[13]: (2020, 3, 4, 12, 7, 23, 387693)
```

But is there also a way to use seconds since the epoch?

Can't seen to find much info on this surprisingly.

Comment: you can get seconds from the epoch as `t=now().timestamp()`. This will return a POSIX timestamp as a float which will be the number of seconds and the decimal part is mili/microseconds. currently gives me `1583324633.451522`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After findng DjangoJSONEncoder I think it's the most simple.
However I don't know if there are any unknown caviots with this.

```
# PYTHON
from django.utils import timezone as tz
t = tz.now() 
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
json.dumps(t, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[18]: '"2020-03-04T12:07:30.323Z"'

t                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[19]: datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 12, 7, 30, 323666, tzinfo=<UTC>)

// JS 
new Date("2020-03-04T12:07:30.323Z")
Date Wed Mar 04 2020 14:07:30 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
```